# I don't know why this relation is NOT antisymmetric

Tags: relations

Given the relation
$$\mathcal{R}=\{(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3), (3,1)\}$$
the problem is to determine whether this relation is reflexive/symmetric/antisymmetric/transitive or not.

I understand why this relation is reflexive, and also why it is not symmetric and transitive.

But the textbook says it is NOT antisymmetric whereas I think it is antisymmetric.

My idea:

Def. of antisymmetry: $x\mathcal{R}y$ and $y\mathcal{R}x \implies x=y$

For $(a,b)$ in $\mathcal{R}$, there are only 3 elements in $\mathcal{R}$ that satisfy the condition "$x\mathcal{R}y$ and $y\mathcal{R}x$"; $(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)$. So the condition "$x=y$" trivially holds for those elements.
Also, there is NO counterexample: that is, there is no $(2,1), (3,2)$ and $(1,3)$ in $\mathcal{R}$.
So I think it is antisymmetric, but the book says it is NOT antisymmetric and there is no explanation.

Am I wrong? Please give your help!

Comment: To me, this definitely looks antisymmetric by the definition you have given in your post. The textbook must be wrong or something.

Comment: You are right.. Maybe it's a typo in your book?

Comment: The relation is antisymmetric, but it is not asymmetric. Is is possible that your book meant asymmetric instead of antisymmetric?

Comment: Good. Thank you for your helps!

Comment: Other point: the relation is only reflexive under the extra condition that it is a is a relation on $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: This is the "$a$ either beats or draws against $b$ in a game of rock-paper-scissors" relation

Comment: Note that without knowing on which set $\mathscr R $ is a relation we can actually not tell whether it is reflexive. If it is supposed to be a relation on $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \} $ then it's not reflexive since it doesn't include $(4,4) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is perfectly fine, there must be a mistake in the book.
You can also use the equivalent form of antysimmetry: 
If $ x \mathcal{R} y $ and $ x \neq y $ then $(y,x) \not \in \mathcal{R} $
which is the second part of your argument